# Why a Windows Device Driver Interrupt Service Routine(ISR) is Interruptible?

Tags: windows, device-driver, isr

I am new to writing Windows Device Driver.

My understanding is that at the hardware level when an x86 processor is interrupted (when the INTR line of the CPU is triggered by the device), the processor clears the Interrupt Flag bit of the EFLAGS register to disable interrupt before executing the Interrupt Service Routine (ISR). So normally, an x86 ISR cannot be interrupted again before it finishes its works and issues an IRET instruction. But why a Windows ISR is interruptible? Is Windows ISR the same as the processor's ISR?

A Windows Device Driver ISR is interruptible according to here:
[MSDN:Writing an ISR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566399%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The processor flag is virtualized by DIRQL, primarily to ensure that a device driver cannot abuse it and leave interrupts disabled for an extended time.

Answer (score 0):

What the documentation specified by you in the link says is :
1. When a interrupt[DIRQL] is raised general rule is all the interrupts w.r.t to that device and lesser than that device IRQL.
2. When a ISR is executing and a  deice with higher DIRQL interrupts then the ISR for the device with higher DIRQL will be called...

so the statement which is specified in the link points to the points i mentioned above.